# Using EL variable of <c:set> inside Facelets <ui:repeat> tags

Tags: jsf, jstl, el, uirepeat

I have a `Home`. Each `Home` has a list of `Room`s. Each `Room` has zero or more `Person`s.

I would like to count total persons of each home. But I can't add a new variable to record person count in any backing beans or entity. So I'd like to count it in the view only via `<c:set>`.

My first attempt look like:

```
<c:set var="personCount" value="${0}" />
<ui:repeat var="home" value="#{mybackingBean.homes}">
    <ui:repeat var="room" value="#{home.rooms}">
        ${personCount += room.persons.size()}
    </ui:repeat>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{home.id}" />
        <h:outputLabel value="#{personCount}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</ui:repeat>
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several mistakes.

---

First,

```
${personCount += room.persons.size()}
```

In EL, the `+=` is the [string concatenation operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el005.htm#BNAIK). So, this will give you basically the result of `String.valueOf(personCount) + String.valueOf(size)`. If the count is initialized to `0` and there are `3` persons, then this will print `03`.

You basically want to re-assign the result of `personCount + size` back to variable `personCount`. You need to re-set the variable using `<c:set>` as below.

```
<c:set var="personCount" value="${personCount + room.persons.size()}" />
```

---

Second,

```
<c:set var="personCount" value="${0}" />
<[for each home]>
    <[for each room]>
        <c:set var="personCount" value="${personCount + room.persons.size()}" />
```

The `personCount` is initialized with `0` outside both iterations. So, for each home you'll this way count the persons of all previous homes as well. You want to declare it inside the first iteration.

```
<[for each home]>
    <c:set var="personCount" value="${0}" />
        <[for each room]>
            <c:set var="personCount" value="${personCount + room.persons.size()}" />
```

This is not EL related. This is just a logic error which would cause the same problem in "plain vanilla" Java as well.

---

Third,

JSTL tags like `<c:set>` run during view build time (during conversion from XHTML template to JSF component tree). JSF components like `<ui:repeat>` run during view render time (during conversion from JSF component tree to HTML output). So, the `<c:set>` doesn't run during `<ui:repeat>` iteration. Thus, it cannot see the iteration variable `var`. You basically need to iterate during view build time as well. You can use JSTL `<c:forEach>` for this.

So, all in all, your intented solution look like this:

```
<c:forEach items="#{bean.homes}" var="home">
    <c:set var="personCount" value="${0}" />
    <c:forEach items="#{home.rooms}" var="room">
        <c:set var="personCount" value="${personCount + room.persons.size()}" />
    </c:forEach>

    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{home.id}" />
        <h:outputLabel value="#{personCount}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</c:forEach>
```

For an in depth explanation, see also [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

---

However, as the `+=` operator apparently doesn't cause an EL exception in your case, this means that you're already using EL 3.0. This in turn means that you can use the new [EL 3.0 lambda and stream features](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el004.htm).

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.homes}" var="home">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{home.id}" />
        <h:outputLabel value="#{home.rooms.stream().map(room -> room.persons.size()).sum()}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</ui:repeat>
```

No need for a counting loop anymore. No, this does not require Java 8, it works on Java 7 as good.